# How to get index of an empty element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, is-empty, isnullorempty

I have a JavaScript array with some empty (maybe null or undefined) elements. I need to find those empty indexes (**1** and **3**).

```
['red',,'orange',,'blue','white','black']
```

But my solution is not working:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === undefined) { // Same problem with null or ''
        console.log('No color: ' + i);
    }
}
```

Snippet:

```js
const array = ['red', , 'orange', , 'blue', 'white', 'black'];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === undefined) { // Same problem with null or ''
    console.log('No color: ' + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to turn your code into a runnable snippet.  Please edit the code to show you ***actual*** attempt with the code in question.  The code that you have seems to already work which implies that aren't creating the array as you describe.  Please add additional details to make this question answerable.

Comment: If the issue is as simple as a missing single quote `'` after the word "black", this is likely a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a blank string to compare to get the answer you desire. If you also want to check for undefined you can use logical or to check both of them.

```
const array = ['red','',  'orange',,  'blue', 'white', 'black'];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] === '' || array[i] === undefined) { 
console.log('No color: ' + i);
}
}
```